# Editor for FormatJS messages

Tags: formatjs

We are using FormatJS and React Intl for a web application of ours, to translate the UI. What we are currently missing is an editor for the messages files.

Does anybody know of a any decent editor for message files? Editing the bare JSON resources is not really an ideal option when dealing with large files.

Thanks,
Gerald